# How can I get the multiple address list(Geocoding) from search a location using here maps api

Tags: api, windows-phone-8, here-api

I want to get multiple address when I search a location. It will be like "here maps" app. I am using the here maps api. I only get one or two location when I use the this api

"http://geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.xml?app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg&mode=retrieveAddresses&gen=7&searchtext=dhaka"

But I need more results like 10 or 20 that will be defined by me. I try a lot but not get any solution. like "maxresults=10" parameter.

N.B: I want to use only one api call and must use the here maps api and also for windows phone 8 app.

Thanks

Comment: Why would you expect an unambiguous request for the city of Dhaka to return more than one result? If you make an ambiguous request for the city of [Toledo](http://geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.xml?app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg&mode=retrieveAddresses&gen=7&searchtext=toledo) multiple results **are** returned. Similarly adding `maxresults=2` restricts the response to the first two results.

Comment: I need the nearest 10 or 20 locations to provide the user locations. So that he can select the exact location form his nearest place.

Answer (score 0):

To obtain the location of an address, you need to make a **geocoding** request:

[http://geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.xml?app_id=**YOUR_APPID**&app_code=**YOUR_APP_CODE**&mode=retrieveAreas&gen=7&searchtext=**TEXT**&locationattributes=none](http://geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.xml?app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg&mode=retrieveAreas&gen=7&searchtext=dhaka&locationattributes=none)

The important parameters are as follows:

- `mode=retrieveAreas` - this will return areas not addresses
- `searchtext=?` - this is your text request
- `locationattributes=none` - this reduces the size of the response to only return a lat/lng

Thereafter you need to make a **reverse geocoding** request to find cities nearby:

[http://reverse.geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/reversegeocode.xml?level=city&minresults=10&prox=23.713,90.399,1000&mode=retrieveAreas&gen=8&app_id=**YOUR_APPID**&app_code=**YOUR_APP_CODE**](http://reverse.geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/reversegeocode.xml?level=city&minresults=10&prox=23.713,90.399,1000&mode=retrieveAreas&gen=8&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg)

The important parameters here are as follows:

- `mode=retrieveAreas` - this will return areas not addresses
- `level=?` - this reduces the responses to a given level - in this case cities - see the [API reference](https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/geocoder/topics/resource-reverse-geocode.html) for details
- `minresults=?` - this ensures that ten city level entities are returned.

Comment: Thanks for helps. But I need only one request to get the nearest locations where I only input the searchtext="Nome of a Location".

Comment: If you want to use `searchtext=xxx` you will be _geocoding_. If you want names of nearby cities you will be _reverse-geocoding_ - you **cannot** combine a mixture of the two services in one request. To ensure your end-user only makes one request there should be no problem setting up  a proxy service which waits on a response from the first request and sends back the response from the second.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you are looking for more like suggestions ? Places API from HERE might be more helpful in that case, but usually an "at" attribute is required for that

http://places.demo.api.here.com/places/v1/suggest?at=23.6364%2C91.0803&q=Dhaka&app_id=demo_qCG24t50dHOwrLQ&app_code=NYKC67ShPhQwqaydGIW4yg

Comment: I want to search the nearest 20 locations by city or area name, not latitude and longitude.